# Stack Exchange blocked by EE - Adult content

Tags: support, blocked, censor

I fired up Stack Exchange on my mobile today and got this:

[image: screenshot]

EE is an ISP and mobile operator in the UK.

This is happening for stackexchange.com and all subdomains, but not SO. It is not affecting the app. When I'm back home I'll see if this can be reported, but giving a heads up in case this is easier to resolve by SE themselves.

Comment: My impression is that it's probably not Stack Exchange's problem if some ISP chooses to block its users from accessing the content they want to access without hassle.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems EE considers most of the web to be unsuitable. Twitter, YouTube, Facebook also blocked.

Comment: Therefore I doubt there's much Stack Exchange can do about it. If you have the option, I'd suggest switching ISPs. If you don't, I'd suggest following their procedure to turn off content blocking.

Comment: @nhinkle I think this is what's to come for all UK isps, I think EE is probably just ahead of the game. It's obviously just been enabled today.

Comment: @fredley Maybe you should consider moving outside of the UK. ;)

Comment: @fredley: It seems unlikely that that is deliberate. Twitter, YouTube and Facebook? Really?

Comment: Did EE fix their false positive filters?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am having a long argument with them via email :-)

Comment: Should be easy: ask them for proof that Stack Exchange has adult only content. Doubt they have. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I'm sure that will work.